# Drush doesn't detect drupal installation under sites sub-directory

Tags: 7, drush

I have been using  Drush 4 and 5 with no problem. Now that I have downloaded and installed new **Drush 7.0-dev** using composer, I am having problem i.e  it doesn't by-default detect drupal installation when I am on sites sub-folder,

Drush running on sites-root directory,

```
drupal7/sites/example.com/modules/views$ drush status

 Drupal version                  :  7.30                               
 Site URI                        :  http://example.com              
 Database driver                 :  mysql                              
 Database hostname               :  localhost                          
 Database port                   :                                     
 Database username               :  example_user                    
 Database name                   :  example_db                     
 Database                        :  Connected                          
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful                         
 Drupal user                     :                                     
 Default theme                   :  bartik                             
 Administration theme            :  seven                              
 PHP executable                  :  /usr/bin/php                       
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini              
 PHP OS                          :  Linux                              
 Drush version                   :  7.0-dev                            
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp                               
 Drush configuration             :                                     
 Drush alias files               :                                     
 Drupal root                     :  drupal7
 Site path                       :  sites/example.com               
 File directory path             :  sites/example.com/files         
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
```

Drush running under sites-subdirectory,

```
drupal7/sites/example.com/modules/views$ drush status

 Drupal version         :  7.30                               
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                       
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini              
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                              
 Drush version          :  7.0-dev                            
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                               
 Drush configuration    :                                     
 Drush alias files      :                                     
 Drupal root            :  drupal7
```

So, how do I configure Drush, is there anything I can do to make it work, I don't want to use `--uri`  or `-l` flag or any other options everytime.

**Update**

Also when I download modules it get downloaded on `sites/all/modules` directory

```
drupal7/sites/example.com/modules$ drush dl webform
Project webform (7.x-3.20) downloaded to drupal7/sites/all/modules/webform.                                     [success]
```

But if I am on sites-root directory it works fine,

```
drupal7/sites/example.com$ drush dl webform
Project webform (7.x-3.20) downloaded to /home/sysop/project/drupal7/htdocs/sites/heisenberg.com/modules/webform.                          [success]
```

Comment: you seem to have some discrepancies in the paths ? ie the first and second status seem to have run in exactly the same place ? and what is htdocs under drupal7 ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an alias conf file named `YOUR_SITE_NAME.aliases.drushrc.php` in sites\all folder with that code.

```
// The site in sites/YOUR_SITE_NAME/ 
$aliases['YOUR_SITE_NAME.local'] = array(
  'uri' => 'YOUR_SITE_NAME_URI',
  'root' => '/path/to/drupal_root_folder',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%dump-dir' => '/tmp'
  ),
);
```

Then clear cache : drush cache-clear drush.

Test your alias : `@YOUR_SITE_NAME.local status`.

To run a command, for the sake of example : `@YOUR_SITE_NAME.local mb MODULE_NAME hook1 hook2 --write`

---

**UPDATE :** **in order to create automatically Drush site aliases** for many sites, place this code in your `aliases.drushrc.php` file.  Drush will look for `aliases.drushrc.php` in the ".drush" folder in your home directory (see [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38347/drush-post-installation-where-can-i-find-drushrc-php#38348) to get sure where to put this file).

```
$aliases = array();
$drupal = '/var/www/drupal';

// Automatic alias for each Drupal site
$site = new DirectoryIterator($drupal . '/sites');
while ($site->valid()) {
  // Look for directories containing a 'settings.php' file
  if ($site->isDir() && !$site->isDot() && !$site->isLink()) {
    if (file_exists($site->getPathname() . '/settings.php')) {
      // Add site alias
      $basename = $site->getBasename();
      $aliases[$basename] = array(
        'uri' => $basename,
        'root' => $drupal,
      );
    }
  }
  $site->next();
}

// Get all site aliases
$all = array();
foreach ($aliases as $name => $definition) {
  $all[] = '@' . $name;
}

// 'All' alias group
$aliases['all'] = array(
  'site-list' => $all,
);
```

You can also read this : [create your own drush aliases](http://drush.ws/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php). You could even think about managing synchronization between remote and local systems ([source](http://dropbucket.org/node/749)).

**EDIT :** as per ericx comment, consider adding `bash-completion`. Drush comes with a bash-completion file, `drush.completion.sh`, which offer alias completions.

Comment: so every time I create new site, there I need to write drush alias, this won't be helpful for multiple site I am using like 1000 or so. :)  previous version of drush works fine out of the box why is it so ?

Comment: where should `aliases.drushrc.php` file be present. I am confused :)

Comment: I updated the answer. By default in the ".drush" folder in your home directory

Comment: I see that alias file is being used by drush,while running the drush command, but the alias is not working for me

Comment: I updated a bit the answer. Does @YOUR_SITE_NAME.local status returns correctly ? I'm afraid I can't help more.

Comment: `drush @YOUR_SITE_NAME.local status`  is working properly..  but it will be an extra thing I will need to put every time I run drush command. may be it's better to switch back to old drush, which does it out of the box. and thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Indeed @shrish this is the correct command line. But it's less typing than moving to the correct directory each time : you just have to name the alias and do whatever you'd like to : `drush @myalias.local do smthing` Sorry if it doesn't fit your hopes.

Comment: I can also recommend that you consider adding `bash-completion`. `drush` comes with a `bash-completion` file, `drush.completion.sh`. Amongst other things, it will offer alias completions for you. Makes it a little less painful.

Comment: @shrish you definitely shouldnt be obliged to create new aliases, this thing should work out of the box :)

Comment: @mojzis that's what I thought :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest getting the 6.x version which is the stable version for D7 (yes, the versioning is slightly confusing :). You should be able to isntall it with

```
composer global require drush/drush:6.*
```

Comment: Drush 4,5,6 works just fine, problem with Drush 7-dev version may be.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Drush Aliases](http://www.astonishdesign.com/blog/drush-aliases-what-why-and-how).

They essentially let you *target* your Drupal installations to run your `drush` commands on.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly, but make sure there is a settings.php file in drupal7/sites/example.com/ and drush/drupal has access to edit that file

--or--

try using the --uri parameter:

drush dl --uri=http://example.com webform

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out that I needed to install mysql-client:

```
apt-get install mysql-client
```

I had the following situation:
drush 4, 5 and 6 worked fine for me.
drush 7, 8 don't work (different errors, including that ones you're describing).
And my MySQL database was located on a separate server.

HTH,
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to run drush from inside the drupal directory post reinstalling drush. It turns out there was a symlink to drush inside that directory that was causing recursion and therefore drush was failing. Removed the symlink and was able to run drush from the directory again.